# sqlite search multiple column

Tags: sqlite, select

am trying to perform a case sensitive serach of all columns in a table, so i did somthing like this

`Select * From mytable Where col1 || '--' || col2 || '--' || etc like '%SomeValue%'`

but it alwas return the same result for both upper case and lower case. if i do this

`Select * From mytable Where col1 like '%SomeValue%' OR col1 like '%SomeValue%' etc`

i get the desired result. The problems here is that i cannot use this second query as i have about 36 columns to search, and writing `col1 like '%SomeValue%'` up to 36 times would be unecessary.

does anyone have any solution?

Comment: You might want to consider sqlite fulltext, breaking text into a words and creating a "long schema" index or words keyed back to identities or a combination.  Seems like scanning 36 columns is the wrong approach ...

Comment: i already went that path, but it makes all other query slow, i got this solution from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428495/select-statement-with-multiple-where-fields-using-same-value-without-duplicati

Comment: Not necessarily the main path for other queries - more like a look up table off to the side for these searches.  That table for searching could also use a fulltext compiled version of sqlite if you want it to be very fast.

Comment: The downside is the extra time to word break/index or you have to make it async/background if some latency on the index is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use `glob` instead of `like`

```
sqlite> select * from sqlite_master where ('foo' || '--' || 'bar') like '%Bar%';
table|t|t|2|CREATE TABLE t (a)
sqlite> select * from sqlite_master where ('foo' || '--' || 'bar') glob '*Bar*';
sqlite> select * from sqlite_master where ('foo' || '--' || 'bar') glob '*bar*';
table|t|t|2|CREATE TABLE t (a)
sqlite>
```

Another solution is to use [`pragma case_sensitive_like`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_case_sensitive_like)

```
sqlite> PRAGMA case_sensitive_like = 1;
sqlite> select * from sqlite_master where ('foo' || '--' || 'bar') like '%Bar%';
sqlite> select * from sqlite_master where ('foo' || '--' || 'bar') like '%bar%';
table|t|t|2|CREATE TABLE t (a)
sqlite>
```